# SymPy's Sympify Function Returns a String, Not a SymPy Object

Tags: python, excel, sympy, openpyxl

I have an Excel file with two columns; the first containing my variable name, and the second containing a mathematical expression typed as a string. Using Python 2.7.12 and openpyxl 2.3.2, I'm importing this data. The string is imported as unicode by default.

I would like to create a Sympy object from my imported string to perform some operations on it. However, in this case sympifying my imported string returns a string object, not a SymPy object. Why is this?

I get the expected behaviour (sympify returning a SymPy object) if I instead hard-code the string into my .py file.

This code illustrates:

```
from sympy import *
import openpyxl

imported_data = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample_workbook.xlsx')
data = imported_data.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')

variable_name = data['A1'].value
variable_value = data['B1'].value
globals()[variable_name] = variable_value

x = symbols('x')

print(type(variable1))      # This is a unicode string
sympy_expr = sympify(variable1)
print(type(sympy_expr))     # This should now be a SymPy object, but it's now of type str
```

[Workbook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrfy.jpg)

[Workbook download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmHbzzyxa9hShoUtXnrVco9ry0CQRw)

Comment: What's with the weird use of globals? Just use variable_value. Anyway, it looks like your problem is that the equation is a quoted string. Strip the quotes from it the conversion works fine.

Comment: Stripping the quotes does indeed cause sympify to convert to a SymPy object - thank you.

I'm using globals() to assign multiple variables as they're imported. In my full problem, I'm importing not one variable from the workbook, but many. I would like to assign each variable (from workbook column 1) to its value (from workbook column 2). I would then like to be able to call that variable using only its name, and avoid the need to use the cumbersome syntax of a dictionary[key] to call the corresponding value every time I need it.

Comment: Dictionary syntax isn't particularly complex but whatever. You really should be using some kind of container object to avoid any possible side effects in populating `globals`.

Comment: It unfortunately adds unnecessary complexity when it's embedded in some long mathematical expressions.

I'll look into alternative container options. Thanks again.